# Google Sign-In - only ask for ID not email and profile scopes

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin, gidsignin

I am using the Google Sign-In SDK for iOS.

I want to get the minimum possible user info from Google so I can then use it as part of my auth system - even just the Google ID would do. But whatever I try, Google tells the user that I'm requesting their email, name, profile picture and language preferences:

[image]

I've tried:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().shouldFetchBasicProfile = false
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = []
```

But it crashes, because Google Sign-In requires you've defined the scopes (or set `shouldFetchBasicProfile = true` which basically means `scopes = ["email", profile]`)

Any idea how to request less data?